# Does the Dual Wield Talent modify the rules about multi-attacks?

Tags: two-weapon-fighting, multiattack, wrath-and-glory

In the The Core Rulebook for Wrath & Glory 2nd edition, the dual wield talent is described as such:

> #### Dual Wield Talent
>
> You can wield two weapons with uncanny accuracy.
> When you wield one weapon in each hand the DN penalty for using the Multi-Attack option is
> reduced by 2. Each weapon must have the Pistol Trait or be a one-handed melee weapon.
> You may also use a different weapon you are wielding for each of your Multi-Attacks, rolling
> damage separately for each weapon.

Can a character with this talent multi-attack the same enemy with both its weapons? What about a "Mob"-type enemy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Possibly.

### RAW

Rules as written you can attack the same enemy multiple times even without the 'Dual Wield' talent. In the 2.1 version of the rules neither in the section for multiactions nor multiattacks does the text explicitly say that the actions/attacks you declare have to be different actions/attacks.

### RAI

But reading through the examples given after these sections however, I do not think that this is the intention. And at higeher tiers of play this would allow characters with high damage dealing weapons to trivially one shot any target.
So if you go with the interpretaion that each attack you make has to be distinct, then it would allow you to attack the same target twice. Once with your left and once with your right. Using to diffrent wapons makes this even clearer. You could be wielding a pistol and a sword. Thus making a melee attack and a ranged attack. Two very different actions. Wielding the same weapon twice should not suddenly forbid this.

### Mobs

Mobs can always be multiattacked as per this paragraph:

> #### Mobs & Multi-Attack
>
> You can use the Multi-Attack to target multiple
> individuals of your choice in a Mob. When you Test to
> hit as part of a Multi-Attack against a Mob, each Icon
> over the target’s Defence means you hit an additional
> target in the Mob, as normal.

#### Of Note

When using a melee weapon you could potentially kill so many troops of the mob with the first attack, that the mob is no longer in range for additional attacks. Though if you still had movement left you could then followup for further attacks.